# Push image to gcr registry through REST calls

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, registry, google-container-registry

I have a golang app running in a kubernetes cluster which must push an image it builds periodically to gcr.io using REST endpoint (There are project constraints that does not allow me to use libraries such as go-containerregistry, docker cli for the push). I understand from documentation that I need to add "X-Registry-Auth" header to the requests to handle authorization. I am retrieving `dockerconfigjson` from imagePullSecret on the cluster (that works well for pod creation) and adding it as header value. However, I get an unauthorized error from gcr endpoint.

```
secret, err := secretsClient.Get(context.TODO(), "imagePullSecret", metaV1.GetOptions{})
secrets := []corev1.Secret{*secret}
keychain, _ := k8schain.NewFromPullSecrets(context.TODO(), secrets)

reg, _ := name.NewRegistry("gcr.io")
authorizer, _ := keychain.Resolve(reg)
auth, _ := authorizer.Authorization()

encodedJSON, err := json.Marshal(*auth)
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
}
authStr := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(encodedJSON) //being used as auth header value
```

Content of authStr created above has the following:

```
{
  "username":"_json_key",
  "password":
    "{\n  \"type\": \"service_account\",
      \n  \"project_id\": \"project\",
      \n  \"private_key_id\": \"porject-key-id\",
      \n  \"private_key\": \"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
      \n  <validkeyhash>
      \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n\",
      \n  \"client_email\": \"something@something.iam.gserviceaccount.com\",
      \n  \"client_id\": \"123344567678786\",
      \n  \"auth_uri\": \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth\",
      \n  \"token_uri\": \"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token\",
      \n  \"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs\",
      \n  \"client_x509_cert_url\":       \"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/manager%40something.iam.gserviceaccount.com\"
  \n}\n",
"auth":"<base64-encoded-imagePullSecret>"}
```